# SVD, infinite matrices and normal operators from a function

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, spectral-theory, svd

I'm trying to understand the behavior the Singular Value Decomposition on a deeper level, and why it might give a particular result. Take the function

$$
f(x,y) = \frac{1}{(1+2x+y)^2}
$$

and consider a continous range of parameters over $x \in [0,1]$, $y \in [0,.5]$. Consider an "infinite" matrix

$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
f(0,0) & f(\delta_1, 0) & f(2\delta_1,0) & ... & f(1,0) \\
f(\delta_1,\delta_2) & f(\delta_1, \delta_2) & f(2\delta_1, \delta_2) & ... & f(1,\delta_2) \\
... & ... & ... & ... & ... \\
f(\delta_1,.5) & f(\delta_1, .5) & f(2\delta_1, .5) & ... & f(1,.5) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

where $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$ can be made as small as I like. I can certainly take a finite, but small value for the $\delta's$ and compute the SVD

$$A=USV$$

This gives some interesting behavior (plotted below in clockwise order $f$, log of the singular values, and the corresponding vectors, $u_i$ and $v_i$):

[image]

## Questions:

Terminology:
Is it correct to think of $f$ as a (normal) operator, or is it $A$? What is this operator?

Spectral theory:
How do you compute the eigenvectors directly from $f$?

Comment: $U S V \to U S V^{*}$